# Left orphan record in Sonata Admin OneToMany relation

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, one-to-many, sonata-admin

I've tow tables (Municipality and Poi) related OneToMany (one municipality has many Pois). So, there is a field in Poi table indicated the related Municipality.

I want allow that Poi elements to stay orphan (with no Municipality assigned).

The Entities in Doctrine are declarated as follow:

```
/**
 * Municipality
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Poc\PocBundle\Entity\MunicipalityRepository")
 */
class Municipality
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Poi", mappedBy="municipality", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    protected $pois;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->pois = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;


public function setPois($pois)
{
    if (count($pois) > 0) {
        foreach ($pois as $i) {
            $this->addPoi($i);
        }
    }

    return $this;
}
public function addPoi(\Poc\PocBundle\Entity\Poi $poi)
{
    $poi->setMunicipality($this);
    $this->pois->add($poi);
}

public function removePoi(\Poc\PocBundle\Entity\Poi $poi)
{
    $this->pois->removeElement($poi);
}
```

... (and the respective getters/setters generated by doctrine:generate:entities)

```
/**
 * Poi
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Poc\PocBundle\Entity\PoiRepository")
 */
class Poi
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Municipality", inversedBy="pois")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="municipality_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $municipality;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;
```

... (and the respective getters/setters generated by doctrine:generate:entities)

In the admin side, MunicipalityAdmin::configureFormFields is defined as follow:

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $formMapper
        ->add('name')
        ->add('pois', null, array('by_reference' => false), array(
            'edit' => 'inline',
            'inline' => 'table',
            'sortable'  => 'position'
        ))
;
}
```

This allow me to add Pois related to a Municipality, and they are recorded in database. But when I want to delete a relation (nor the Poi completely, only the relation and left the Poi orphan) nothing happens.

I can force to delete it if I configure the Municipality entity as follow:

```
@ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Poi", mappedBy="municipality", cascade={"persist"}, orphanRemoval=true))
```

... but in this way, obviously, I'm not only deleting the relationship between Municipality and a Poi, but the Poi itself. The desired behavior is to unset the relationship, I mean, left the Poi.municipality_id field of this record as null.

I'm tracing the actions and see that this line ..

```
    $this->pois->removeElement($poi);
```

... is executed when I remove an item from the list, but value of `$this->pois` is identical before and after this line.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the line where set the poi.municipality_id to null...

```
public function removePoi(\Poc\PocBundle\Entity\Poi $poi)
{
    $this->pois->removeElement($poi);
    $poi->setMunicipality(null);
}
```

And done!